Antivirus detects Script:SNH-gen Trj in Elementor files
Avast antivirus detected Script:SNH-gen Trj in a website with Elementor plugin.
File path: /wp-content/plugins/Elementor/assets/js/webpack.runtime.js
Can this be a false-positive or is it an actual Trojan? Did anyone else detect it?

Same situation...and today also with frontend.min.js... i use avast

Here's the Virustotal report (including Avast) for the same file from Elementor 3.22.3 (the current version at time of writing), which comes up completely clean. You could use a diff tool to compare your copy of the file against a clean copy downloaded from plugins.wordpress.org to make doubly sure, but I'd err on the side of caution and assume your site is compromised. Recovering from a compromised site is off topic for this Stack, but there's plenty of information out there.

I'm having this same problem. I've proved Avast is showing as a false positive, by scanning and also replacing the contents of the file with fresh data.
I've also duplicate the site onto a different domain and Avast does not detect anything on the new site, it seems to being flagging only the url and there is nothing wrong with the file in question. Very strange

I've got the same issue. Only the url is different. In my case the notice is about the file elementor/assets/js/frontend.min.js
